# Address ng decimal numbers to datagridview

Tags: c#

Have been trying to make my datagridview accept decimal numbers from front end. And ny datagridview table is binded to a database, tried setting default cell value but stil could nt accept floating digits

Comment: So whats the question here?

Comment: How can i make my datagridview table accept floating numbers from the front end

Comment: What are you using ? Winforms ? WPF ? ASP ?

Comment: Asp.Net @ zohirSalak

Comment: Thanks sorted it out my dataset was accepting int instead of float